# Using \vafont from http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/va/

Tags: fonts

So I installed this, http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/va/, package to use this font and I wish to use it inline for a single character.

I'm not sure how to do this, please help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have installed the package correctly, then add

```
\usepackage{va}
```

to your preamble. Then you can say

```
This will typeset the single character {\vafont q} in the font.
```